# c - how to create a single function that handle different data type in an array

Tags: arrays, c, function

I would like to create a function that can modify the last element of a static array, **but which could work with different type of data** (int16_t, uint16_t and float)

I have managed to make it work for each kind of data but in different functions. And I would have like to design a **single function** that can handle each of them.

Here is the snippet for float elements.

```
void fifo_datas_update_float(float data_in, float *datas, uint8_t size)
{       
    datas[size-1] = data_in;        //assign new value to last element
}

const uint8_t dtsize = 3;
static float datas_fake[dtsize] = {10,20,30};
float new_value = 40;
fifo_datas_update_float(new_value, datas_fake, dtsize);
```

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Unless you have a `union` this will be so man flavours of *not fun*.

Comment: You can't use a single function, but using macros and [generics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) it's possible.

Comment: thanks for yours comments. I actually thought about another solution which would be to use simple function overloading with one definition each type. I have tried it and works perfectly. I don't if it's the proper way to do it... What do you think about it ?

Comment: C doesn't have function overloading. That's where aforementioned `_Generic` comes into play.

Comment: OK Sorry, I forgot to mention but it could also be a c++ solution... :)

Comment: For C++ you don't have `_Generic`, but you have templates, and of course overloading. Please note that C and C++ are two *very* different languages.

Comment: Re "*it could also be a c++ solution*", That would be a different question with different answers.

Comment: Why not use a macro? `#define update_last(elem, arr, size) ((arr)[(size) - 1]=(elem))`

Comment: @ikegami yes I fully agree. @ tstanisl Yes I think it's what Someprogrammerdude suggested but I would like to avoid doing it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some_programmer_dude remarked in a comment, you can use `_Generic` (since C 2011) as below.
*Note that you can use only 1 generic association, so I made one of the arguments a `(void *)`.*

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
#define update_last(n, X, p) \
        _Generic((X), \
            float *: updatef, \
            default: updatei16, \
            uint16_t *: updateu16 \
        )(n, X, p)
 
// src must have type (int16_t *)
void updatei16(size_t n, int16_t a[static n], void *src) {
    a[n-1] = *(int16_t *)src;
}
 
// src must have type (uint16_t *)
void updateu16(size_t n, uint16_t a[static n], void *src) {
    a[n-1] = *(uint16_t *)src;
}
 
// src must have type (float *)
void updatef(size_t n, float a[static n], void *src) {
    a[n-1] = *(float *)src;
}
 
int main(void) {
    float ff[1] = { 2023 }, fff = 3.1416F;
    uint16_t uu[1] = { 2023 }, uuu = 42;
    int16_t ii[1] = { 2023 }, iii = -1;
 
    printf("%f, %"PRIu16", %"PRId16"\n", ff[0], uu[0], ii[0]);
 
    update_last(1, ff, &fff);
    update_last(1, uu, &uuu);
    update_last(1, ii, &iii);
 
    printf("%f, %"PRIu16", %"PRId16"\n", ff[0], uu[0], ii[0]);
 
    return 0;
}
```

See https://ideone.com/aAqvTU

Output of the code above is

```
2023.000000, 2023, 2023
3.141600, 42, -1
```

Comment: BTW: with adding the proper functions you can `update_last()` with `char`, or `long double`, or `struct whatever`, ...

Comment: Thanks it was exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for having mixing everybody up with c and c++ jumble

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```c
void set( void *a, size_t i, void *val_ptr, size_t ele_size ) {
   char *p = a;
   memcpy( p + ( i * ele_size ), val_ptr, ele_size );
}

set( datas_fake, dtsize-1, &new_value, sizeof( *datas_fake ) );
```

But that doesn't save you anything over calling `memcpy` directly.

```c
memcpy( datas_fake + dtsize-1, &new_value, sizeof( *datas_fake ) );
```

Comment: I got the following error with gcc12.2.0 on Debian: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
   17 |    char *p = a;

Comment: @QC4R try `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error bad compiler` / `#endif`

Comment: @QC4R You appear to be compiling the code as C++, but the question is tagged C.

Answer (score 0):

To build up on @pmg's answer, you can use:

```
#define gen_update(_suffix, _type) \
    void update_##_suffix(size_t n, _type a[static n], void *src) \
    {   a[n-1] = *(_type *)src; }

gen_update(ld, long double)
gen_update(d, double)
gen_update(f, float)
gen_update(ull, unsigned long long)
gen_update(ll, long long)
gen_update(ul, unsigned long)
gen_update(l, long)
gen_update(u, unsigned)
gen_update(i, int)
... 
// And so on.
```

to avoid duplication.